# Send Lightning events only to nested components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I have a nested component structure

```
<c:parent>
   <c:child />
   <c:child />
</c:parent>
```

and I want `c:parent` to send a COMPONENT event which is received by the `c:child` components.

I don't want to use **Component methods** as this would required the parent to find the children using their `aura:id` which is not loosely-coupled anymore.

I also don't want to use APPLICATION type event because they might trigger something outside of the containment hierarchy of `c:parent`.

**Can I make COMPONENT events travel down? And which special markup do I need for that?**

Comment: From the documentation: `Component events can only be handled by components above them in the containment hierarchy so their usage is more localized to the components that need to know about them.`

Comment: I dont think component events can travel down it can only be handled by some component above in the containment hierarchy. My understanding of this event concept is that these events propogate up the DOM chain and they can either be handled in Bubble or capture phase. It never trickles down below.

Comment: @MartinLezer please use a real answer and provide the a link to the documentation. Any idea on how to restrict the application event to "only go down" the hierarchy?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "aura:id which is not loosely-coupled anymore".  For the application event, only the components which defined the handler relative to the event will receive the event. Will you use the same event for other components?

Comment: @MartinLezer: I planned on making it generic as this is needed for any parent to child communication. Is there anything I can do to just allow the event to travel down or maybe stop it before it travels too far?

Comment: @Robert, Even if it travels too far, It will only be handled by components which has a handler for it?.Are you worried about performance. The whole reason for application events is for them to get handled by any components in the page and not just by ones in the containment hierarchy.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know any solution for this. I don't think this is possible. Or I am missing something. For me, the best solution is using aura:methods on the child components.  If you want to make it generic, maybe you can define a base component which this aura:method, then inherit from this component on all your child components.

Comment: Nonetheless if you add your answer with a link I make it my preferred answer.

Comment: Maybe someone will come with the right solution :D If not, you'll be able to answer your own question with your favorite solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll want to use an application event; see the [application event life cycle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_propagation.htm).

The trick here is that you must call stopPropagation on your event from `c:parent` in order to set itself as the "root" for the application event. This will limit your event's scope to just components within your own hierarchy. The following should suffice:

```
<!-- parent -->
<aura:component>
  <aura:registerEvent name="customEvent" type="c:myCustomAppEvent" />
  <aura:handler name="customEvent" event="c:myCustomAppEvent" phase="capture" action="{!c.setEventRoot}" />
  <!-- code for your children here -->
</aura:component>
```

---

```
({  // Parent's controller
  setEventRoot: function(component, event, helper) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
})
```

---

At this point, your child component simply needs to have an `aura:handler` to handle the event, like normal.

Comment: Awesome insight. As always with you ;-)

Comment: Looks like they changed the behaviour. You can't handle an application event if you define its name. It worked for me by removing the name attribute of the handler.